# Wifi: Connection activation failed. Active connection removed before it was initialized/ Ubuntu experienced internal error

Tags: wireless

I've been able to connect just normally to my home WIFI, but now it seems to not let me. I've looked into several similar posts and tried most of the solutions but none worked.

Also, most of the times I turn on the computer I get the error "Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal", as well none of the proposed solutions worked for me.

I could post the details but there a lot of words, let me know what specific part is needed.